# Vuejs index.html <link> tags not respecting relative path

Tags: html, css, vue.js, hyperlink, relative-path

I am trying to deploy a built Vue app on a web server NOT using the root path and my relative links are referencing the root. Has anyone successfully tackled this?

I have tried setting publicPath to "", "./", and "." with no success. My app is being deployed at mydomain.com/dev and my index file links look like `<link href="css/my.css">` once built

vue.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    publicPath: "./"
}
```

index.html

```html
<link href=css/app.f262a66a.css rel=preload as=style>
<link href=css/chunk-vendors.d92c4b75.css rel=preload as=style>
<link href=js/app.384925b6.js rel=preload as=script>
```

I would expect that these links would try to load files from `mydomain.com/dev/css/app.f262a66a.css` but they are loading from `mydomain.com/css/app.f262a66a.css` and therefore I am getting a 404 response.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Just try to set the `publicPath` in your `vue.config.js` like this:

```
module.exports = {
   publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
      ? '/dev/'
      : '/'
}
```

See the [documentation](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#publicpath) on that.

Comment: We are going to be working with multiple environments, all with their own subpath on the domain (dev, test, prod) and we use the same dockerfile to build for all of them. We could put conditionals in the dockerfile, for the node env but it seems like a lot of overhead rather than getting the relative paths to work.

However, thank you for the note and if I can't make relative paths work, I'll look into this route.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to go around this by setting the public path via an environment variable. Doesn't totally solve the relative path issue, but at least it provides the correct functionality and is able to be controlled on an environment basis.

```
module.exports = {
   publicPath: process.env.PUBLIC_PATH
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is old, but there is no accepted answer, so I'll give it a try.

This fixed my issue:

In `vue.config.js` (at the root of your Vue's project directory):

```
module.exports = {
    publicPath: '././',
  }
```